# UITableView cell selection disabled and UITableViewHeader Enabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am adding a my header view to

```
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView=headerView;
```

This tableView has 10 cells.

I want to disable the cell Selection but, **headerView** touch events must be enabled.

To achieve this I added the following code:

```
self.tableView.userInteractionDisabled=YES;
self.headerView.userInteractionDisabled=NO;
self.headerView.exclusiveTouch=YES;
```

Where I am wrong?

Basic idea of implementation is , If **headerView** is enabled then **cell selection** is disabled and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely understand what you are asking, but if you want to avoid seeing any cell highlighting set the UITableViewCell selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone. That's what I do, and then don't implement the UITableViewDelegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.

I've never tried it, but I'm pretty sure you can also disallow the selection of any rows by setting the UITableView property allowsSelection to NO.

The userInteractionDisabled property of the table view should be set to NO. Otherwise your headerView, which is a subview of tableView, will not get touch events. Setting a superview's userInteractionDisabled property to no disables touch events for all of its subviews.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Using selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone did work. When A view in header is clicked it opens a UIImageView covering "some part" of the screen. When one taps on the image it goes back to its original position.  So, this "some part"  overlaps few cell's. When I click on the image , which definitely overlaps few cell, it fires didSelectRowAtIndex instead it should fire tap associated with image.

Comment: I see. Well it depends on how you've implemented  the showing of the UIImageView. A touch is intercepted by the front most view, but it that view doesn't handle it, then it passes to the view behind it. In this case, it seems your UIImageView isn't handling the touch, so it is being passed to the table view cell. How are you adding the UIImageView?

Comment: UIImageView is in tableViewHeader. When I tap on it , it surely maximises the image. After that it overlaps cell. So, when I tap back on the image, it passes the event to  didSelectRowAtIndex.

Comment: Well I'm guessing that you've added the touch handling to headerView, and the UIImageView is a subview of headerView. I'm guessing that the UIImageView increases in size beyond the bounds of the headerView. Maybe try adding a touch handler to the UIImageView, and make sure that the clipsToBounds property of headerView is set to NO. (Which is the default value).

Comment: if clipToBounds was YES, then it would not have maximise the image.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right about that, assuming that you are adding the UIImageView as a subview to the headerView and not the tableView. The clipToBounds part of my comment is not really relevant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16147/discussion-between-andypaul-and-darren)